# CSS :active for a child to hide another child

Tags: html, css

I want to minimize `#test` by pressing `#btn` without JS. I'm writing this:

**CSS**

```
  #test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: all 350ms;  
    -o-transition: all 350ms;  
    -moz-transition: all 350ms;  
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #wrapper:first-child:active #test {
    width: 0px;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "wrapper">
  <button id = "btn">BTN!!</button>
  <div id = "test">e wvwe</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f3NeA/1/

Unfortunately, `:active` relates to `#wrapper`, not `:first-child` (ie `#btn`).
How to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. You might want to check out this handy article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Your first-child selection did not work because #wrapper is not a first child. `:first-child` relates to children of the same parent.

Equally, your previous selector was trying to select an id of #test that was **within** that first child and your div is not within the button...even if the first child selector had worked.

So you need to select the button element that is a direct child of #wrapper and hence`>` and  then the adjacent sibling which requires `+`.

With that you get....

```
  #wrapper > button:active + #test {
    width: 0px;
  }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3NeA/4/)

Finally, you should be aware that `:active` only works while the mouse button is held down. If you want to switch that to a 'click' you would need Javascript (or a JS library like JQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Update your selector to `element+element` selector as follows:

```
#wrapper button:active+#test {
  width: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f3NeA/8/

Answer (score 1):

Use '+' selector to select the immediate sibling of the button:

```
#btn:active + #test{
    width: 0px;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/f3NeA/10/)**.